# overlap save method zero padding fft gibb's phenomenon

Tags: filter-design, frequency-domain, overlap-save

i'm doing overlap save method in frequency domain. i make hankel function to digital filter using frequency sampling method(to make arbitrary magnitude phase filter). and i do ifft and zero padding fft

i heard that if the filter is non-causal, zero padding fft have gibb's phenomenon. my filter have same problem. i'm doing shift FIR filter to make causal filter but the problem is not solved.... please help me

```
    clear all;
    close all;

    %% parameter
    
    fs = 2000;
    ts = 1/fs;
    c = 340;
    R = 1;
    
    %% hankel filter     
    Lp = 50;
    N = 2*Lp+1;                     %filter length
    resol = 0:N-1;                  % frequency resolution
    f = resol/N*fs;
    k = 2*pi*f/c;
    M=5;
    R = 2;
    nu = 2;                   %hankel order
    
    
    % frequency sampling method

    right = besselh(nu,k(1:(N-1)/2 +1)*R); %Hankel function 0~pi
    right(1:5) = 0;                     %eliminate infinite part
    left = fliplr(right);              
    left = conj(left);                  
    left(end) = [];
    
    H = [right left];               % symmetric freuqnecy response
    h = ifft(H);                % impulse response   
    
    nn = 80;                        %shift index 
    h1 = [h(nn : end) h(1:nn-1)];   % shift impulse response to make causal filter
    H1 = fft(h1,2*N);               %zero padding fft

    
    subplot(2,1,1)
    plot(h1)
    subplot(2,1,2)
    plot(abs(H1))
```

Comment: Your `H` is not conjugate symmetric so that `h` is not real, please check your code. To eliminate the ininite part, why do you set `right(1:5)` to zero? $H_\nu(z)$ goes to infinity only when $z=0$ due to the property of Neumann function.

Comment: i edit code Thank you. 1:5 is  when frequency resolution is high first some part have very high value. So i  do 1:5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gibbs phenomenon is caused by frequency sampling method. I recommend you to use window method instead. It is fast, convenient and robust, although not optimal. BTW, the frequency range should be 0~fs/2, I've fixed it in the following code

```
clear;
close all;

%% parameter
fs = 2000;
ts = 1/fs;
c = 340;

%% hankel filter     
Lp = 50;
N = 2*Lp+1;                     % filter length
NN = 2^nextpow2(N * 100);       % NN >> N
resol = 0:NN-1;                  % frequency resolution
f = resol/NN*fs/2;              % you miss /2 here
k = 2*pi*f/c;
M = 5;
R = 2;
nu = 2;                   %hankel order

% window method
right = besselh(nu,k(1:(NN-1)/2 +1)*R); %Hankel function 0~pi
right(1:200) = 1;                     %eliminate infinite part
left = fliplr(right);              
left = conj(left);                  
left(end) = [];

H = [right left];               % symmetric freuqnecy response
h = ifft(H);                % impulse response   

h1 = ifftshift(h);   % shift impulse response to make causal filter
win = hann(N).';
h2 = h1(NN/2-N/2:NN/2+N/2-1) .* win; % windowed impulse response
H2 = fft(h2,2*N);               %zero padding fft

figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(h2)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(abs(H2))
```

Frequency sampling method:

[image: Frequency Sampling]

Window method:

[image: Window]

Comment: OMG............Very Very Very Thank you so much

Comment: if error is large, is this normal?

Comment: @ggh I don't see significant error between these two methods.

Comment: there is some wrong part. i fixed. Thank you very much

Comment: Could i ask one more question?? How can i make non-causal filter? that didn't use ifftshift command??

Comment: @ggh why do you want this? You can't implement a non-causal filter in real world.

Comment: please see my new question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81424/non-causal-cascade-filtering-process-in-frequency-domain